# Mysql query to search data into Mysql if column contain multidimensional array in JSON form?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json, json-extract

I have a product table under which i have create field name : **`product_attributes`** under which I have stored all product attributes in json data as show below:

```
{"color":["Red","Green","yellow"],"size":["XL","M","XXL","L"],"Brand":["Nike","Fila","Addidus","Lotto"],"Gender":["Male","Female"]}
```

Every product have there own attributes in the same format as given above. some product have same attributes and some have different for example :

```
{"color":["Green","Blue"],"size":["XXL","L"],"Brand":["Nike"],"Gender":["Male","Female"]}
```

Now I want to search products based on up mentioned data : user have option to search product based on attributes as we did on eCommerce websites

Example :

-- *Color* : ( Red **or** Green ) **AND** *Size* = ( XXL **or**  XL )  **AND** *Gender* = ( Male )

-- *Size* : ( XL ) **AND** *Color* : ( Yellow ) **AND**  *Brand* : ( Nike **or** Lotto )

so based on the above example user can search any thing as per his requirement so, I need a MySQL query which return me data based on selected attributes if found under any products

Please have a look on product table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `products` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL,`product` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`product_attributes` longtext NOT NULL,`price` int(11) NOT NULL)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

-- Dumping data for table `products`

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `product`, `product_attributes`, `price`) VALUES(1, 'product 1', '{\"Color\":[\"White\",\"Red\"],\"Size\":[\"Large\",\"XL\"],\"Brand\":[\"Nike\",\"Lotto\"],\"Gender\":[\"Female\",\"Male\"]}', 12),(2, 'product 2', '{\"Color\":[\"White\"],\"Size\":[\"XL\"],\"Brand\":[\"Fila\"],\"Gender\":[\"Female\"]}', 21),(3, 'Product 3', '{\"Color\":[\"White\",\"Red\",\"Black\"],\"Size\":[\"Large\",\"XL\"],\"Brand\":[\"Fila\",\"Addidus\"],\"Gender\":[\"Female\"]}', 15),(4, 'Product 4', '{\"Color\":[\"White\",\"Red\"],\"Size\":[\"Large\"],\"Brand\":[\"Fila\"],\"Gender\":[\"Male\"]}', 18);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql version? Background info [eav](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). Do you have a table structure? Edit the question to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for clarity.

Comment: *i have create field name : product_attributes under which I have stored all product attributes in json data* This is very bad structure for your task...

Comment: My Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB

Comment: @Akina could you please suggest me the best way to manage it ? In future we have to create Single and variation products as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: See the comment provided by @danblack - it answers to this question. [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) pattern is safe for your task.

Comment: I mean to provide [this eav link](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) which has a reference to [mariadb's dynamic columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/) supported in your version.